# Joomla: how to add script to header?

Tags: javascript, joomla3.0

First thing first the page where I have the script:

https://www.glansbeton.be/uitvoering/
(the floating button with gratis offerte aanvragen)

this is my script code:

```html
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
$document =  Factory::getDocument();
// Add script
$Script = "
    <script>;
        jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
            if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 70) {
                jQuery('.extensionbuy_now').addClass('btn-".$lftrght."');
            } else {jQuery('.extensionbuy_now').removeClass('btn-".$lftrght."');
            }
        });
    </script>";
    
if($btn_align == 0)
{
    $CAlign .= '$(document).ready(function(){ $("#buttn").addClass("zero"); });';
}
else if($btn_align == 50)
{
    $CAlign .= '$(document).ready(function(){ $("#buttn").addClass("fifty"); });';
}
else
{
    $CAlign .= '$(document).ready(function(){ $("#buttn").addClass("hundred"); });';
}

if($btn_float == 0)
{
      $CFloat .= '$(document).ready(function(){ $(".extensionbuy_now").addClass("btn_zero"); });';
}
else
{
      $CFloat .= '$(document).ready(function(){ $(".extensionbuy_now").addClass("btn_hundred"); });';
}

$Script .= '<script type="text/javascript">';
$Script .= $CAlign;
$Script .= '</script>';
$Script .= '<script type="text/javascript">';
$Script .= $CFloat;
$Script .= '</script>';
```

If I simply echo the script:
echo $Script;

The output is working like it has to be.   So my script is good and working.
Now I want to place the script outside the body.

```
$document->addStyleDeclaration($style);
```

This is not working.
Did read a lot, but I don't know how to do this.
Can someone give me some advice?

Comment: If you are doing Joomla work, please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and ask your Joomla-related questions there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely clear on where you're trying to implement this but see if the following helps:

```
<?php
   $document = JFactory::getDocument();
   $document->addScript('/media/system/js/sample.js'); // path to js script
?>
```

Comment: Hi David, we are NOT seeing enough of you on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.  We have an election occurring right now, but you aren't quite over 150 rep there.  How about we get you to post a few awesome answers and make you eligible to vote?!?  We can always use high-rep users from elsewhere in the network to help bring up the standard at JSE.  I hope to see you there.